# Access localhost of Docker container

Tags: docker

I am running docker on mac and am trying to set up a development environment for an angular project in a docker container.

My docker-compose setup currently looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "${DOCKERFILE_DIR}"
    working_dir: "${CONTAINER_DIR}"
    ports:
      - "3000:4200"
      - "3001:8080"
    volumes:
      - "nfsmount:${CONTAINER_DIR}"
    tty: true

volumes:
  nfsmount:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
      device: ":/System/Volumes/Data/${SOURCE_DIR}"
```

The thing is, when I run `ng serve` inside the docker container, it serves to the `localhost:4200` of the docker container and not to the exposed ports of the container. This means that the port mapping of `"3000:4200"` is insufficient for me to connect `localhost:3000` from my host machine to `localhost:4200` of my docker container.

Sure, an easy solution would just be to serve to `0.0.0.0:4200` of my docker container by using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` instead. However, I am trying to mimic my development environment as much as possible, so I was wondering if there was any other way to connect `localhost:4200` to `0.0.0.0:4200` inside my docker container (or better still, connect `localhost:3000` of my host machine directly to `localhost:4200` of my docker container).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way you are setting up your containerised development environment is not correct. You shouldn't be editing source files inside the container unless they are mounted from host machine. You might lose your work when the container exits. You also need to start the development container using `docker-compose up` command which sets up the port binding between host machine as specified in the compose file. Can you share the dockerfile.

Comment: You do need the `--host 0.0.0.0` setting, there’s not a shortcut around it.  I’m not clear you actually need Docker to do Angular development, though; what do you gain over just using Node on the host system directly?

Comment: @ShashankV The source file is indeed mounted from the host machine. As I am using docker on mac, I am using NFS to optimize the performance of the volume mounts. You can refer to https://vivait.co.uk/labs/docker-for-mac-performance-using-nfs for details.

Comment: @DavidMaze It is a full stack app with many dependencies (of specific versions). I am using docker because I want to isolate its environment from my host machine and also because I do not want to install these dependencies on my host machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you use host networking inside the container. When you create a container, the container gets it's own network namespace. The loopback interface is accessible only to the processing running in the same network namespace i.e., the processes inside the container only and hence cannot be accessed from the host.

Instead of running your container in separate network namespace, you can run it in the host network using `network_mode: "host"` parameter in the docker compose. This should work for your use case if you insist on not binding to 0.0.0.0 inside the container. - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode